# how to print full text in one line using for loop in c?

Tags: c, for-loop, cs50

I am using the for loop to add one to each character in a string and print them out but when printing them each letter is formed on a new line, I am a beginner in C language by the way. Any generous help would be appreciated. btw, I know they are each letter is printed because of how the for loop works but I don't know how to fix it

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++)
{
    char c = plaintext[i];
    printf("CipherText: %c\n", c + 1);
}
```

This is the output:

```
Plaintext: hello
CipherText: i
CipherText: f
CipherText: m
CipherText: m
CipherText: p
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `\n` (newline) character.
(and a couple of other suggestions.)

```
int main(void)
{
    char plaintext[] = "this is original cipher";
    char c = 0;//create this before entering loop
    size_t len = strlen(plaintext);//assign length to variable that can be used in for statement
    printf("%s", "CipherText: ");//print this before entering loop
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
         c = plaintext[i];//output each char in sequence
         printf("%c", c + 1);//output each char in sequence
    }
    printf("%s", "\n");//Optional = moves the cursor to the next line in case
                       //there are follow-on lines to printf
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

For the given example 'plaintext', here is the output:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("CipherText: );
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++)
{
char c = plaintext[i];
printf(" %c", c + 1);
}
```

Comment: That was the output.... CipherText:  iCipherText:  fCipherText:  mCipherText:  mCipherText:

Comment: Why 2 printf's? You can do `printf("CipherText: %c", c+1);`.

Comment: @Lucas if you do in 1 printf, then "CipherText" will print in every loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a bit shorter version:

```
printf("Ciphertext:");
for (const char *i = plaintext; *i; i++)  printf("%c", *i + 1);
```

or without the pointers

```
printf("Ciphertext:");
for (size_t index = 0; plaintext[index]; index++)  printf("%c", plaintext[index] + 1);
```

instead of `printf` in the loop you can use `putchar` but most optimizing compilers will do it for you

Comment: @ryyker then no pointer version - but correct. correct types are used, no unnecessary string traversion

Comment: Okay, Admittedly, It is a good solution.  But since I do not typically do embedded, or anything that any any way requires avoiding the very idiomatic construct of using a `for()` loop with a string length as an exit criteria, I rather enjoy seeing (and using) _string traversing_ in code, even if it is unnecessary.  And, in case you still care, I did change the type from `int` to `size_t` in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in this short way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char str[] = "hello";
  printf("PlainText: %s\nCipherText: ", str);

  for( int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    putchar(str[i] + 1);

  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
PlainText: hello
CipherText: ifmmp
```

Every character which starts with a `\` is called an escape character and when you are printing you ciphered text, you're printing it every time with an escape character `\n` called **new line** character. This is the reason why every character in the ciphered text is getting printed on a new line. Just remove `\n` from `printf("CipherText: %c\n", c + 1);` and you'll get your expected output.

You can also learn more about escape characters [on this Wikipedia page about them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C).

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the \n (newline) character from the for loop. Unlike Python C wont add a new line unless you add the \n.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");  // asking user to enter a word             
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(plaintext); n > i ; i++) // looping through each entered letter
    {        
            printf("%c" , plaintext[i] + 1);   // changing the letter by 1 place                     
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```